# How to pass parameters to ARM template using azure python sdk?

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk

i run the following command as a bash script.

```
az group create -n $1-rg -l eastus2

az deployment group create -g $1-rg -n $1-deploy \
  -f ./azure/sensor/trafficmirrorstack.json \
  -p @./azure/sensor/trafficmirrorstack.parameters.json \
  -p CustomerName=$1

az deployment group show -g $1-rg -n $1-deploy
```

the following seems like it should work:

```
  rg_name = f"{name}-rg"
    deploy_name = f"{name}-deploy"
    region = list(region_params.keys())[0]

    # add resource group
    rg_result = resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(
        rg_name, 
        {
            "location": region
        }
        )
    print(f"Provisioned resource group {rg_result.name} in the {rg_result.location} region")
    with open("./sensor/trafficmirrorstack.json") as template_file:
        print("!!!!1")
        print(f"{0}".format(template_file.read()))
        #print(f"{0}".format(template_file.read()))
        print("!!!!2")
        template = f"{0}".format(template_file.read())

    parameters = {"CustomerName": { "value": name}}
    deployment_params = { 
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": template,
        "parameters": parameters
    }
    # Create deployment
    deployment_create_result = resource_client.deployments.begin_create_or_update(
        rg_name,
        deploy_name,
        {"properties": deployment_params},
        # deployment_params,
    )
    deployment_create_result = deployment_create_result.result()
```

but how do you do the equivalent of  "-p @./azure/sensor/trafficmirrorstack.parameters.json -p CustomerName=$1"

thanks in advance

Comment: According to my understanding, you want to overwrite one key/value pairs in the parameter file. Right?  If so, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2020_10_01.models.deploymentproperties?view=azure-python. We cannot use parametersLink and parameters at the same time.

Comment: my intended question was i can do multiple  "parameter" designations in the azure cli.   in my example above "-p @./azure/sensor/trafficmirrorstack.parameters.json" is a file and "-p CustomerName=$1" is name value pair.  "    parameters = {"CustomerName": { "value": name}}
    deployment_params = { 
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": template,
        "parameters": parameters
    }". seems to only allow one of these

Comment: my issue is similar to this github issue.  [https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/478] only adding the addition complication of multiple parameter designations.

Answer (score 0):

When we use Azure python sdk to deploy arm template, we just can use provide the paramater file URL or define parameter as json with the method  `resource_client.deployments.begin_create_or_update`. we can not use the two method at the same time. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2020_10_01.models.deploymentproperties?view=azure-python)
[image]

Besides, in azure cli, it will read  multiple "parameter" you provide then define one Jobject with these "parameter" as `parameters` when we deploy arm template. For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/a3604d1f872b3671e2bb17948a47f0e7be5dbb07/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/command_modules/resource/custom.py#L312)

Comment: Thank you. i would mark that resolved but i do not have enough reputation points.  so silly that azure cli allows but sdk does not.

Comment: that document says you can not have uri and file but not both.  not file and values